# Spring Jpa Creating Duplicate rows while Saving Parent save(parent )and Child Entity save(child)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA,
It might be basic Question

I have created two Entity Java Class: `Users` and `Role`

In `Users` class, I have given the users `@OneToOne` relation to role.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role  {
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private int roleId;
    
    @Column(name="role_name")
    private String roleName;
}
``
```

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@IdClass(UserRoleId.class)
@Table(name = "user_role", schema = "labmodule")
public class UserRole {


    @Id
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private int roleId;
    
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    
    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }
    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public UserRole(Audit audit) {
        super();
        this.audit = audit;
    }
    public UserRole() {
        
    }
    public Audit getAudit() {
        return audit;
    }

    public void setAudit(Audit audit) {
        this.audit = audit;
    }

}
```

``

I have created a User Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>
```

and in a similar way, I have created Role Repository

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, String>
```

And now while adding new user details.
I am saving entries in the Users table

```
user.setFromDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
user.setLoginDisabled(false);
Date date = new Date();
user.setActive(true);
userRepository.save(user);

UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
userRole.setRoleId(user.getRoles().getRoleId());
userRole.setUserId(user.getUserId());

userRole.setAudit(audit);
userRoleRepo.save(userRole);
```

I also want to save some additional audit values in the user_role table.

Issue: In the new Relation table
I am getting duplicate entries,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLP0j.png)

I have tried
saveandflush user and save userRole
and
insertable=false updatable=false in the @jointable

Thanks in Advance

Comment: in your code you wrote `userRole.setUserId` but I don't see a userId field in `UserRole`. If you left that out, please do not. Please update your post with the fields of your classes. Don't think that something isn't relevant and post less information, most of the times that missing information is the reason something isn't working correctly

Comment: I have added UserRole Class as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

So you are not associating a created user role to a user. do This:
first save a user role and then it will create a user role with an ID in it. Then add that role into the user object and save it.

```
UserRole userRole=   new  UserRole();
userRoleRepo.save(userRole);
user.setFromDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
user.setLoginDisabled(false);
Date date = new Date();
user.setActive(true);
user.setUserRole(userRole);
```

Also I recommend having one to many from user to user roles, since in most cases you have to have user having multiple roles.